# Basecamp3 Jquery ui datepicker not opening

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, basecamp

```
function init() {

    $('.message-composition__footer')
    .prepend('<input type="text" id="datepicker_1" placeholder="Select date" class="input input--pilled event-form__date-input u-hide-focus" readonly>');

    let dp = $( "#datepicker_1" );
    console.log(dp);

    $(dp).datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            schedule_date = dateText;
            $( dp ).val(dateText);
            console.log("schedule_date - " + schedule_date);
        }
    });

};

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    console.log('turbolinks:load');
    init();
});

(function($) {
    console.log('new-message script loaded');
    init();
})(jQuery);
```

'turbolinks:load' event fires successfully but datepicker does not work. 
if I reload the page then it works. I'm stuck here for 2 days now, please help.

Datepicker after reloading page
[image]

Datepicker without reloading page (when 'turbolinks:load' event fires)
[image]

Comment: Why fire `init()` twice?  [Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/3kx1jhyt/) with a simplified version of your code, it runs fine.

Comment: I'm trying to run init() on 'turbolinks:load' event, the input box #datepicker_1 gets prepended but the datepicker not working. Basecamp3 does not reload pages and therefore I have to rely on that particular event to fire my script.

Comment: I have no idea how reloading will give you a different result.  I also have no idea what `turbolinks` is or how Basecamp3 is involved. The arrow function is an obviously unusual thing (which AFAIK does not work in IE11 and earlier), have you tried with a normal function instead?